# Get data from object in array - REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, react-native, object

I am currently stuck getting information from a weather API. I can reach the data what are NOT in an array but just an object. But the WEATHER array I can't get! See image! No error shown in console!

**this works:**

```
.then((json) => setData(json.coord))

<Text style={styles.h1}>{data.lon}</Text>
```

But getting into weather not! Help would be appreciated!

[This is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv0wW.png)

[weather API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOpJC.png)

Fetching data from API and trying to get **json.weather**

```
const Weather = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rotterdam&appid=f7c5a6722f37c1cb782a66e9b904178')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.weather))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  });



  return (
    <View>
      <NotiScreen/>
      <Text style={styles.h1}>{weather.id}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What did you try to get the `weather`? Please share that also.

Comment: Tried : { data.weather[0].id } Error: undefined is not an object.

Comment: Ok, what does console(data) returns or in jsx what does this `<pre>{data}</pre>` returns ?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it by:**

**Changing:**

```
.then((json) => setData(json.weather))
```

**To:**

```
.then((json) => setData(json.weather[0]))
```

**Text element:**

```
<Text style={styles.h1}> {data.main} </Text>
```

**It didn't worked before because when I tried this method, the api blocked me out for too many requests!**